# Is there a way to have a semi transparent circle with a completely transparent background and completely opaque box in the middle?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, transparency

I need to have a 'tower' represented by a black rectangle, that is fully opaque. I, also, need to have a circle representing its range it can shoot in that is semi-transparent. This all needs to be a pygame.Surface surface with a fully transparent background. I am obviously using this in a class if that needs to be clarified. I know how to have a semi transparent surface but I can't get it to have a transparent background, instead it's just a black box.

Comment: see examples with [transparency in PyGame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create surface and convert to surface with alpha channel.

```
 surface = surface.convert_alpha()
```

Nex you have to fill it with color which has `alpha=0` in `[R,G,B,Alpha]`

```
 surface.fill([0,0,0,0])
```

And you have empty surface with transparent background.

Now you can draw with different transparency - you have to use colors with `alpha` - `[R,G,B,Alpha]`.

For example half-transparent circle (`transparency 50%` = `alpha=128`)

```
pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0, 128), (100, 100), 100)
```

With `alpha=0` it will be invisible, with `alpha=255` it will be fully opaque.

---

If you have `.png` with transparency then you can use `.convert_alpha()` after loading to get transparency.

```
image = pygame.image.load("file.png").convert_alpha()
```

---

See examples with [transparency in PyGame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/transparency)

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, this one really stumpted me but your solution has worked perfectly!